# How do I get specific values from a datasnapshot in flutter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I have this datasnapshot

```
"{post1: {pic: https://i.redd.it/ni6zhxh874011.jpg, title: title, desc: desc}, post2: {pic: https://i.redd.it/krj9miojg5011.jpg, title: awsdas, desc: desc2}}"
```

and I would like to retrieve the "pic" values from each post. snapshot.value["pic"] does not work it returns null.

thanks in advance

this is how I recieved the datasnapshot for my future builder

```dart
Future<Object> _obj () async {
    Object _objdatabase;
    await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Communities").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(_objdatabase.toString());

        _objdatabase = snapshot.value; 
    });
    return _objdatabase;
}
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that Daniel is talking about the Realtime Database and not Cloud Firestore.

Comment: show us example how you retrieve the snapshot.

Comment: have you tried snapshot["post1"]["pic"]

Comment: I would but "post1" would be a push value.

Comment: what do you mean push value?

Comment: in firebase you can specify data to be uploaded with a random string as its name like "post1" so there's no way of knowing what it would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is what i did

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;

map.values.toList()[index]["pic"]
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are sure **snapshot** have child's use **value** member as **Map Object**

```
snapshot.value['key'];
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to iterated over `values` in your snapshot.value and add them to a list.

pseudo-code:

```
for (var value in snapshot.value.values){
myList.add(value);
}
```

Then you will be able to do something like this depending on your use case:

```
myList.forEach((v)=>print(v["pic"].toString)); //just an example
```

Comment: This does not work. " Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' "  Can you provide a complete example of what to do with the snapshot?

Comment: I think you forgot to remove .value , should be `for (var value in _obj.values)`

Answer (score 0):

This code retrieve the key of node:

```
DataSnapshot usuario = await messagesRef.limitToLast(10).orderByChild("email").equalTo(mail_emparejar).once()
.then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
print(snapshot.value);
user_uid=snapshot.value.entries.elementAt(0).key;
........
```

result=6TLD6RFIa0T0a3CuRW9FpB4HlXf2

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for flutter :

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
   query: databaseRef,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index) {
      return ListTile(
         title: (snapshot.value != null) ?
                   Text(snapshot.children.first.value.toString()) 
                   : Text("No Data")
      );
   },
),
```