# Retrieve Map Data in Firebase to Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data structure
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcLao.jpg)

I need to call all the item in the FavDestination collection and here is my code in Flutter

```
child: StreamBuilder(
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('FavDestination').snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot){
if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading Data... Please Wait');
return
ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length, //snapshot.data.document.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
DocumentSnapshot destination = snapshot.data.documents[index];
//DocumentSnapshot destination = snapshot.data.document[index];
return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => DestinationScreen(
                        destination: destination,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

It retrieves the data successfully, and if the user taps on the document, it will go to Destination Screen and I need to retrieve all the data in activities, here is my code in the Destination Screen

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 15.0),
          itemCount: widget.destination['activities'].length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DocumentSnapshot activity = widget.destination['activities'][index];
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                       Container(
                          width: 120.0,
                          child: Text(
                          activity['name'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
```

and here is the Error I got
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cELh3.jpg)

any idea how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: The error states that activity['name'] is null. That means that you either not retrieving your data correctly or you are not handling them correctly. I can not say unless I see the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `activities` field is nested map. On first level you have field `Bali1` which is map as well. And it the code activity is trying to get `name` on first level.

I suppose you should work more on `destination` object structure. You can print it out to analyze and try to map object like `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` and Bali1 as well.

I don't have playground to do it fast, but I found similar approach here:
[How do I get specific values from a datasnapshot in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554737/how-do-i-get-specific-values-from-a-datasnapshot-in-flutter)

I hope it will help!