# The operator '[]' isn't defined

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting an error on this code while getting User's information from firebase database

```
     Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
  {
      id = snapshot.key;
      email = snapshot.value["email"];
      name = snapshot.value["name"];
      phone = snapshot.value["phone"];
  }
```

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554737/how-do-i-get-specific-values-from-a-datasnapshot-in-flutter

Comment: Print `snapshot.value` and see what what comes.

Comment: From the error message it looks like `snapshot.value` returns a primitive value instead of the map that your code expects. It' impossible for us to say why that is, as you're not showing how `snapshot` is initialized, nor the database structure at that location. The best recommendation from this point is as Josteve also commented: print `snapsot.value` and check if that explains the error message.